# Return document on update elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I'm updating user data

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
    "doc" : {
        "name" : "new_name"
    },
    "fields": ["_source"]
}'
```

Heres an example of what I'm getting back when I perform an update

```
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "type1",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 4
}
```

How do I perform an update that returns the given document post update?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is a little misleading with regards to returning fields when performing an Elasticsearch update. It actually uses the same approach that the Index api uses, passing the parameter on the url, not as a field in the update.

In your case you would submit:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update?fields=_source' -d '{
    "doc" : {
        "name" : "new_name"
    }
}'
```

In my testing in Elasticsearch 1.2.1 it returns something like this:

```
{
  "_index":"test",
  "_type":"testtype",
  "_id":"1","_version":9,
  "get": {
    "found":true,
    "_source": {
        "user":"john",
        "body":"testing update and return fields",
        "name":"new_name"
      }
   }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html